# Can't receive SMS

Tags: java, android, sms, receiver

i want send and receive SMS using `SmsManager`, for the sending SMS it's ok, but i can't receive the SMS, i'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` this is my code for send :

```
public void sendMultipartSMS(byte[] packer) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> messageParts = sms.divideMessage(strMessage);
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(strPhone, null, messageParts, sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);
    }
```

and this for receive SMS :

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private String TAG = SmsReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.e(TAG,"onReceive");
            // Get the data (SMS data) bound to intent
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

            String str = "";

            if (bundle != null) {
                // Retrieve the SMS Messages received
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                // For every SMS message received
                for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    // Convert Object array
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    // Sender's phone number
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
                    // Fetch the text message
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                }

                // Display the entire SMS Message
                Log.d(TAG, str);
            }
        }
}
```

also in my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<!-- Declare SMS Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

there is somting is missing ?? the BrodcastReceive doesn't work

Comment: On which android version you are testing ? and whats the targetSDk? Did you asked for runtime permission if >=API23 ?

Comment: where have you specified phone number to whom you want to send SMS?

Comment: you are allright @ADM , i forgot to add this in my activity

String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if ( grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
        }